# how to center text vertically in a div data-role="button" in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a div data-role="button" with an image inside in JqueryMobile.
When using an image the text goes to the top and I cant find a way to center it vertically.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/2srMp/1/

```
<div data-role="button" onclick="someFunction()">
    <img align="left" width="35px" src="http://www.google.com/get/topcontributor/images/icons/icon-android.png"/>
    Button 1
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ui-btn-text{      
    line-height:43px;   
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/2srMp/2/show/)